# Reload data source in android media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seek

I'm having a hard time with media player in android. Basically I try to play a song from my sd card which is downloading (some sort of streaming). So after the song was downloaded (20%) the song starts to play and if I leave it like this it works fine until the end. But if I try to seek at the end (over 20%) obviously it won't work because my seek position is over EOF file so I made this code inside a method

```
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(sFilePath);
        mp.prepare();
        int offset = (progress * mp.getDuration()) / 100;
        if (sCompleted) return;
        sLastSeek = offset;

        if (offset > sMediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
            sMediaPlayer.reset();
            sMediaPlayer.setDataSource(sFilePath);
            sMediaPlayer.prepare();
       } else {
           sMediaPlayer.seekTo(offset);
       }
```

Where `sMediaPlayer` is my mediaPlayer, and `sFilePath` is the file path. In theory the case I presented should be covered but when I seek over the file length the player is reseted (as the code says) but is not playing and this is very awkward and is over my powers.

Comment: Did you try calling start before seekTo(), If you dont call start() , playback won't resume automatically. Also you should use async method for prepare called 'prepareAsync' for streaming app.

Comment: Yes, the player is already started, and already tried with prepareAsync() but the result is the same.

Comment: One small add, I created this app for android 4.0, because i saw on google forums that on android 2.1 there was a problem with seekTo() method so here is not the case anymore

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the mediaPlayer stopt because it reaches the end of the song. Either start it again, refresh the file in steady intervals (say every 5 secs), or just use onCompletionListener. In the last case, when the file ends, you can reload the file and continue playing... mp.getCurrentPosition() to get where it left off playing.

I also noticed you refer to sMediaPlayer, but your MediaPlayer is defined as mp.